# Revolution Slider and Advanced AJAX Page Loader

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using Advanced AJAX Page Loader to load page on ajax and have a problem with Revolution Slider. After loading pages on ajax slider don't work. I'm try to recall slider by revolution API (put this code in "Reload Code:")

```
revapi1.revkill(); revapi1.revstart();
```

But result the same.

Comment: You haven't shown us nearly enough code for us to debug the problem.

Comment: @Adam. That is what close votes/flags are for. It's our job to answer proper questions, not waste time nudging OPs into posting proper questions over multiple iterations.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Can you point to some documentation for that? I was under the impression that prompting for more code/information is an appropriate use of the comments. Especially for new users who might not be entirely clear how to ask a SO question properly.

Comment: @Adam. True, although there is always some burden on OP to make at least some effort to make a proper question. The question should still be close-voted immediately, after which OP may edit and reopen. I will find the meta post for you in just a minute.

Comment: Here you go: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256328/2988730

Comment: And a duplicate: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260263/2988730

Comment: More advice: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572/2988730

Comment: Here's the global meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98022/346663

Comment: I was unaware that was the best practice, thanks for the links, I've voted to close and hopefully, the question asker comes back with a better-formed question.

Comment: Yup. The idea is to keep the site clean without losing potential teaching moments. OPs should get help formulating a good question, not help towards finding an answer to a crap question. Good questions should of course be answered directly, but that doesn't apply here.